# How to add a background picture for a figure in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to add a background picture to go the full size of the figure but I'm not being able to do so. For some reason, when I try to add the background picture it get's added to one of the subplots but never the whole figure.

I have a Figure that contains 4 subplots each containing pie charts, but when I add it replaces one of them.

If not, is it possible to add a logo and any position I want Instead of a background picture?

Comment: What have you done to solve this? Did you e.g. read the documentation and had a look at the [watermark image](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/watermark_image.html) example?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest sorry that file does not exist

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I've tried googling and reading stackoverflow threads but none of them have answered my question yet.

Comment: Yeah, it's html instead of htm at the end.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Great, thank you I will have a look at this